# EJS: How can I render two or more populated colletions from mongoose in EJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I've a issue related to render in EJS two or more populated collections from mongoDB.

In order to pass a most rich context of my "problem", I'll share with you guys some of my code here: models, routes and views.

**Model Schema**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var playerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    namePlayer:         String,
    email:              String,
    playerTeam: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:  "Team"
        },
        nameTeam: String
    }
});

var coachSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        nameCoach:  String,
        email:      String,
        nameTeams: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Team"
        }   
    ]
});

var teamSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    nameTeam: String,
    teamPlayers: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Player"
        }
    ],
    teamCoaches: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Coach"
        }       
    ]   
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Player", playerSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Coach", coachSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Team", teamSchema);
```

**Router Schema**

```
var express = require("express");
var passport = require("passport");
var router  = express.Router();
var Player = require("../models/player");
var Team = require("../models/team");
var Coach = require("../models/coach");

// Find Team by ID
router.get("/resultTeam", function (req, res, next) {

    var teamId = req.query.team;

    Team.findById(teamId).populate("teamPlayers").populate("teamCoaches").exec(function(err, currentTeam) {   
        if(err){
           console.log(err);
        } else {
           console.log(currentTeam);
           res.render("./player/resultTeam", {teams: currentTeam });
        }
    });
});
```

**console.log(currentTeam)**

```
{ teamPlayers: 
   [ { equipe: [Object],
       _id: 5b20023443589331491e0903,
       namePlayer: 'Zico',
       email: 'lorem@ipsum.com',
       __v: 0 },
     { equipe: [Object],
       _id: 5b215e6460adc33528d29f06,
       namePlayer: 'Pelé',
       email: 'lorem@ipsum.com',
       __v: 0 } ],
  teamCoaches: 
   [ { equipes: [Object],
       _id: 5b1f063b999c3c285aa9f3e7,
       nameCoach: 'Harrison Ford',
       email: 'lorem@ipsum.com',
       __v: 1 } },
  _id: 5b1f061c91b4a7284b6d4945,
  nameTeam: 'Real Madrid',
  __v: 1 }
```

Having pasted all my code and expected output here, what I'm trying to achieve now is exhibit in my frontend (ejs file) some basic information about my "team":

**View File**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><i class="fa fa-image"></i></th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Athlete</th>
        <th class="hidden-phone"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Coach</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Email</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <% teams.teamplayers.forEach(function(player) { %>    
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="basic_table.html#"><%= player.namePlayer %></a></td>
        <td class="hidden-phone"><%= coach.coachName %></td>
        <td><%= player.email %></td>
          <td>
            <form style="display: inline" action="/player/<%= player._id %>" method="GET">
               <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

With this last code (ejs view) everything is working properly, until I add this line:

```
<td class="hidden-phone"><%= coach.coachName %></td>
```

Obviously this is wrong, bu I've no idea how can I populate "Coaches Name" for every single athlete or team without to put a second forEach statment, which is not gonna work as well.

By the way, I readed a lot about this issue and I couldn't find the best approach to solve it... looks like **async function** is a possibility here, but honestly, I'm not sure.

Probably the solution is easier than I think, but after 13 hours I'm not capable to figure this out by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coach` object does not exist. You do have `teamCoaches` however, which is an array. Not sure if there ever can be more than one coach, if you should adjust your logic to loop through `teamCoaches` the same way you loop through `teamPlayers`.

If it is always one coach below code should work:

```
<td class="hidden-phone"><%= teamCoaches[0].nameCoach %></td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The insertion of array syntax [0] in fact did the trick.. 
+1 for you help... unfortunatly my reputation is not high enought in order to show my vote. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your object there is **currentTeam** and that's where you should get the object properties from like this:

```
    <tbody>

    <% currentTeam.teamplayers.forEach(function(player) { %>    
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="basic_table.html#"><%= player.namePlayer %></a></td>
        <td class="hidden-phone"><%= coach.coachName %></td>
        <td><%= player.email %></td>
          <td>
            <form style="display: inline" action="/player/<%= player._id %>" method="GET">
               <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

on the this line `<td class="hidden-phone"><%= coach.coachName %></td>` please edit it like so: `<td class="hidden-phone"><%= player.coachName %></td>`

that should be just fine then